# Upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to 5.7 - where is "apply" in mysql-apt-config?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, installation, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.5

I currently have MySQL Server 5.5.54 on my Ubuntu 14.04 image, and I'm trying to upgrade it to 5.7. I'm following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7) as faithfully as possible. Here's a step by step walkthrough of what happens and where I get hung up:

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.0-1_all.deb
```

Ok that's fine.

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.0-1_all.deb
```

I get the following views, such that when I hit "enter" with a highlighted answer, it goes to the other view:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Where is the linked 'Apply' option described in this [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7)?